# memory leak when navigate to page on ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I use Ionic Framework for my hybrid app.  I first open login page. If user logins, it goes dashboard page. It is ok. My problem is that navigating between pages. When it goes from login page to dashboard page, memory ge bigger about 20-30 Mb. Then this grows more when continue to navigate pages. Has anyone give me an idea about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello miyamotomusashi, which syntax you are using for navigation.

Comment: I generally use $state.go("xxx") . Also, I use in html < a href="#/xxx"></a>